# Tcl TCL_OK usage example

Tags: tcl

Based on the help page for the Tcl [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/catch.htm) command, I was trying to use the specified result variables like `TCL_OK` or `TCL_ERROR`. However, there is some problem with the syntax of how those variables should be accessed. Does anyone have a code example that uses those variables instead of magic numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, you want to use the numerical values, not the names. The names are used when programming in the C api but, from Tcl, one just uses the numbers.

```
set code [catch {
    my script
} result]
switch -exact -- $code {
    0 { 
        puts "normal command completion"
    }
    1 { 
        puts "code threw an error (ie: error 'wtf')"
    }
    2 { 
        puts "code used 'return' command normally"
    }
    3 { 
        puts "code used 'break' command"
    }
    4 { 
        puts "code used 'continue' command"
    }
}
```

Comment: So those constants - like TCL_OK - are not available in general Tcl scripting? I'd like to stick with constants and avoid magic numbers as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think they're available anywhere at the scripting level. That being said, the values have been constant for a very long time and they won't be changing (short of a major Tcl rewrite). The 0 result in particular is used in [if { [catch { script } result] } ...] code everywhere. Changing it would break almost every significant Tcl script.

Comment: @user1476056, these numeric codes are documented in the [`return` command manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm#M5). As you can see there, the meaning of this numbers is fixed and codified.

Comment: If you're using `try` (in Tcl 8.6) then the `on` clause will take `ok`, `error`, `return`, `break` or `continue` as well as numeric codes. You can also use those names in `return -code` and with tcltest.